# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone worked wrong on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios11

On iOS 11，I found that

"*reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone*"

sometimes  call  "*tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath*"

**after**  "*tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath*"

for the specific "indexPath" I passed in.

And the cell for specific "indexPath" will change it's height from **Some height** to the **right height**.

Any one has met this problem, too？

Answer (score 3):

well...I found that on iOS 11, you need to explicit **set estimatedRowHeight to 0** if you are using frame layout for cell